# Pointing to an extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm doing this tutorial on how to setup your environment in creating a firefox extension and I don't understand this part:

> Pointing to an extension
>   In your development profile folder, you will find a folder named extensions. In it, you will have code for all your installed extensions. Instead of placing your code there, you can create a pointer file. Do that by creating a file with a unique name for you (this will have to be the same as you chose for your em:id value in your install.rdf file – more on that below).

This part can be found in this link: [How to develop a Firefox extension](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)

I am doing it in Ubuntu. Is this the same as creating a symbolic link? I am confused on this part.

Answer (score 3):

No, not all operating systems that Firefox runs on have symbolic links - so a different mechanism had to be invented. You need to create a text file with the name matching the extension ID and with the path to the extension directory as its contents. A symbolic link with the same name pointing to this directory should do just as well but might be less resistant if the extension manager decides that an update is available for your extension (update installation will remove the symbolic link and replace it by a regular extension install, not sure whether this happens with a text file as well).

Personally, I realized that properly installing extensions produces more consistent results - you don't get the ugly situation where some parts of your extension are updated while others are not. This is why I wrote [Extension Auto-Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/autoinstaller/) (note: this is self-promotion), it simplifies the installation process a lot - especially when you are developing a restartless extension.

Comment: wow this is so epic. I will try this first and let you know if I'm successful. Thanks! :)